# How to use otftotfm with LGR encoding

Tags: math-fonts, mathastext

I have an OTF font with 4 variants (regular, italic, bold, and bold italic). The font includes upper and lower case Greek symbols in all of the appropriate slots.  I'd like to use this font with pdfLaTeX (not XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX) because I need to have the ability to use `\psfrag` substitutions.

I successfully generated all of the LaTeX support files and the PFB files using the instructions found in the article [TUGboat, Volume 34 (2013), No. 1](https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb34-1/tb106tennent.pdf).

Everything works great for text.  Now I would like to try using the `mathastext` package so that all (or most) math will match the text.  On the first pass, this works (for numbers and letters) but not for Greek but

I realized that I did not generate the support files for `LGR` encoding when I ran `autoinst` the first time.  So I went back and reran `autoinst` and added in the `-encoding=OT1,T1,LY1,TS1,LGR` flag.  However, I obtain the following message:

```
otftotfm: encoding ‘lgr’ not found
```

I have perused [this article](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/249405/how-to-use-adobe-source-sans-greek-letters/249558#249558) that discusses `otftotfm` and `LGR` encoding but it only casually mentions "expert use of `otftotfm`".  I have also looked at the manual page for `otftotfm` but can't find any mention of `LGR` encoding but perhaps I am missing something.

So, my question is has anyone tried to do this and can point me to the appropriate section of a manual page or instructions that discusses this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Answering my own question) ---

Turns out by default my Texlive distribution did not include an `lgr.enc` file so I "borrowed" one from the `minion` package and renamed it to `lgr.enc` and all is well now.